# Can not install juju from "go install"

Tags: juju, golang

I had already config golang env on ubuntu os and go get juju from github to my local lab .

I can successfully run  following command,

```
1.  godeps -u dependencies.tsv
2.  make install-dependencies
3.  go test -v ./state -gocheck.v -gocheck.f="StateSuite|CleanupSuite"
```

But when I run ,

```
cd cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/juju/juju
go install -v github.com/juju/juju/
```

nothings happend , no errors , no juju binary file in GOPATH/bin  directory .

Is there something I missed ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are running the command from the root of the juju project, you will want to omit the github.com/juju/juju part of the go install command.

```
go install -v ./...
```

Comment: thanks!  I had successfully compiled juju from source code .